# create pull down from folders in nuke, then evaluate first pull down to populate second pull down inpython

Tags: python, syntax, panels, nuke

I am trying to create a panel that opens on nuke start up and sets a few parameters.

What it is I want to do is have a series of pulldowns on the same panel, the items in the pulldowns will be from folders.

Problem I am having is, I would like to set the first pull down and from the choice of this pull down the second pull down reflects that choice and it menu items reflect that change and so on with each pull down, basically digging down a folder structure but each pull down result is used a variable.

I have not got very far but

```
    import os
import nuke
import nukescripts

## define panel

pm = nuke.Panel("project Manager")

## create pulldown menus

jobPath = pm.addEnumerationPulldown( 'project', os.walk('/Volumes/Production_02/000_jobs/projects').next()[1])


seqPath = pm.addEnumerationPulldown('sequence', os.walk('/Volumes/Production_02/000_jobs/projects').next()[1])


shotPath = pm.addEnumerationPulldown('shot', os.walk('/Volumes/Production_02/000_jobs/projects').next()[1])


print jobPath
print seqPath
print shotPath

#pm.addKnob(job)
#pm.addKnob(seq)
#pm.addKnob(shot)

pm.show()
```

also the strings that appear in the pull downs are surounded by [' ' and so on?

cheers
-adam

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a `PythonPanel`, rather than the old-style `Panel`, which is basically a TCL wrapper. That way, you can get callbacks when the knobs in the panel are changed.

Here's a basic example:

import os

```
import nuke
import nukescripts.panels


class ProjectManager(nukescripts.panels.PythonPanel):
    def __init__(self, rootDir='/Volumes/Production_02/000_jobs/projects'):
        super(ProjectManager, self).__init__('ProjectManager', 'id.ProjectManager')

        self.rootDir = rootDir
        self.project = self.sequence = self.shot = None

        projectDirs = [x for x in os.listdir(rootDir)
                       if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootDir, x))]
        self.project = projectDirs[0]
        self.projectEnum = nuke.Enumeration_Knob('project', 'project', projectDirs)
        self.addKnob(self.projectEnum)

        self.seqEnum = nuke.Enumeration_Knob('sequence', 'sequence', [])
        self.addKnob(self.seqEnum)

        self.shotEnum = nuke.Enumeration_Knob('shot', 'shot', [])
        self.addKnob(self.shotEnum)

        self._projectChanged()

    def _projectChanged(self):
        self.project = self.projectEnum.value()
        projectDir = os.path.join(self.rootDir, self.project)
        projectSeqDirs = [x for x in os.listdir(projectDir)
                          if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(projectDir, x))]
        self.seqEnum.setValues(projectSeqDirs)
        self._sequenceChanged()

    def _sequenceChanged(self):
        s = self.seqEnum.value()
        if s:
            self.sequence = s
            seqDir = os.path.join(self.rootDir, self.project, s)
            seqShotDirs = [x for x in os.listdir(seqDir)
                           if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(seqDir, x))]
        else:
            self.sequence = None
            seqShotDirs = []
        self.shotEnum.setValues(seqShotDirs)
        self._shotChanged()

    def knobChanged(self, knob):
        if knob is self.projectEnum:
            self._projectChanged()
        elif knob is self.seqEnum:
            self._sequenceChanged()
        elif knob is self.shotEnum:
            self.shot = self.shotEnum.value()


p = ProjectManager()
if p.showModalDialog():
    print p.project, p.sequence, p.shot
```

Note that this example is only to demonstrate the basic design of a `PythonPanel` subclass. It has a few small logic issues (in the context of Nuke), and is written to be as clear as possible, rather than as efficient or idiomatic as possible.

Anyway, hopefully this gives you an idea of how to go about building what you're after.